# Figure is put in the center of the page

Tags: floats, positioning, subfloats

I made a figure containing subfigures, but it keeps appearing in a whole page, so lots of white space. I don't know why.
This picture explains what i mean:

[image: problem]

This is the code used:

```
\clearpage
\begin{figure*}[t]
\centering
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_no_of_levels}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_entropy}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/k640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_no_of_levels}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_entropy}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x640_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}}\\
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_no_of_levels}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_entropy}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}}
\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=.33\linewidth]{../Hussein/MatFiles/Lights/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms/x320_Sensor_Lights_On_1000mm-pgms_mean}}
\caption{aaa}
\label{fig:rulascore}
\end{figure*}
```

Comment: Have you seen [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017)

Comment: I've quickly went through it. Is it a problem with the code itself or a simple trick will solve this?

Comment: If you're using `\clearpage`, then it will internally start a new page, and using only a float on that page, causes it to be vertically centred as you showed. What do you have other than this figure in your code? Is there anything following it? Is it at the end of a chapter? Also, why are you using `figure*`?

Comment: Yes there are other pics and text after it. I'm using figure* as i want it to stretch in a 2 columns page.

Comment: @user1460166: So remove the `\clearpage` and see what happens.

Comment: @user1460166 Don’t forget to upvote answers that helped you! (At all your questions)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about changing

```
\begin{figure*}[t]
```

to
    `\begin{figure*}[t!]`?
It overrides some internal LaTeX parameters, giving more flexibility.